# How to zoom in SVG picture freely in Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg, flutter-image

I am using [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package to show svg picture in flutter but I want to be able to zoom into this picture without losing the svg properties of keeping the resolution, I have tried to use [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) for zooming capabilities and [flutter_svg_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider) to use svg picture as image provider but it's not working properly.

So is there a way to be able to zoom and move freely in SVG picture in Flutter?

Comment: Define 'not working properly' as propably you can use [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) for your problem

Comment: The image is completely ruined, with Black areas everywhere, the image is just not right

```
PhotoView(
                            imageProvider: Svg('assets/img-26.svg',
                                source: SvgSource.asset, size: Size(500, 400),),)
```

Here is how I use it

Answer (score 4):

To zoom and move freely in an SVG picture you can simply use ***[`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)*** widget which is built in Flutter SDK itself and allows you to zoom and pan its child Widget. The *[`minScale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/minScale.html)* and *[`maxScale`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer/maxScale.html)* properties control the minimum and maximum zoom levels. Also, do not forget to add the image asset to `pubspec.yaml`<sup>***1***</sup> in case you're using local `svg`. If you're using network image, then you can use the SVG  *[`SvgPicture.network`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#getting-started)* function to load an SVG image from a URL. Also, you can use *`SvgPicture.asset`*(like in the below example) or *`SvgPicture.file`* if your SVG is located in your app's `assets` or device storage, respectively.

```dart
// ...rest
body: Center(
  child: InteractiveViewer(
    minScale: 0.5,
    maxScale: 4.0,
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
      "assets/images/sample.svg", // Replace with the name of your SVG file
       height: 200,
     ),
   ),
),
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://flutlab.io/sandbox/b3941b02-b1ac-4e4f-b63d-10c1236ba956)***

**Output:**

[image: Output for sample run]

---

##### <sup>1</sup>Adding an image asset:

1. Create an `assets` folder at the root level of your project.
2. Inside the `assets` folder, you can create subdirectories to organize your assets, such as an `images` folder for image assets.
3. Place the `svg` image inside the `images` folder.
4. Open your `pubspec.yaml` file and add the assets section under the `flutter` key. Something like:

   ```yaml
   flutter:
     uses-material-design: true
     assets:
       - assets/images/your_image.svg
   ```

Comment: Good updates! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

##### Result

[image]

##### Explanation

You can use [`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) to achieve what you want with custom animations.

#### Code

```dart
class PinchZoomSvg extends StatefulWidget {
  final String urlImage;

  const PinchZoomSvg({
    Key? key,
    required this.urlImage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PinchZoomSvg> createState() => _PinchZoomSvgState();
}

class _PinchZoomSvgState extends State<PinchZoomSvg>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TransformationController controller;
  late AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<Matrix4>? animation;

  final double minScale = 1;
  final double maxScale = double.infinity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = TransformationController();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    )
      ..addListener(() => controller.value = animation!.value)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    animationController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Center(
        child: buildImage(),
      );

  Widget buildImage() => Builder(
        builder: (context) => InteractiveViewer(
          transformationController: controller,
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          panEnabled: false,
          minScale: minScale,
          maxScale: maxScale,
          onInteractionStart: (details) {
            if (details.pointerCount < 2) return;

            animationController.stop();
          },
          onInteractionEnd: (details) {
            // only executed if interaction ends with no fingers on screen
            if (details.pointerCount != 1) return;

            resetAnimation();
          },
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  widget.urlImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),
        ),
      );

  void resetAnimation() {
    animation = Matrix4Tween(
      begin: controller.value,
      end: Matrix4.identity(),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
    );

    animationController.forward(from: 0);
  }
}
```

You can now use the widget whenever you want:

```dart
Center(
  child: PinchZoomSvg(
    urlImage: 'assets/logo.svg',
  ),
),
```

##### Credits

The code in this post was inspired by [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/QPhyTzPqZ5Q?si=oIcWa4IyjM96-T49) - please watch it (until minute 3:24) as it will explain the code in detail.

##### Notes

- Don't forget to import [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg).
- Add the SVG file to your `pubspec.yaml`.